# First assembly file.. Need help making it bootable.

Tags: assembly, x86

```
Bits    16
org 0x7C00
jmp Main

;In= si = string, ah = 0eh al = char, Out= character screen
Print:
lodsb
cmp al, 0
je  Done
mov ah, 0eh
int 10h
jmp Print

Done:
ret

Main:
mov si, msg
call Print

cli
hlt

msg db  "Hello world!",0


times 510 - ($-$$)  db  0

dw  0xAA55
```

So I got this simple assembly code and I have compiled it into a .bin but I need help getting it bootable from an iso. I am going to use virtual player to boot it but I got this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed all the online instructions on how to make a bootable image? Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: I have followed online instruction, however they are to build floppy images and not cd iso images. I got the bin file but cannot figure out how to build an iso with it. I am on windows 7 x64.

Comment: How about something like this (from Google "build bootable CD image widows 7"): http://www.winiso.com/support/tutorials/make-windows7-bootable.html

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the Intel Conventions

Replace:

```
dw 0xaa55h
```

with:

```
db aah
db 55h
```

The Problem is that  dw 0xaa55h would be stored as db 55h, aah, because if a word is loaded from RAM or stored to RAM, the lower byte is on the lower offset. (reverse)

After compiling, check whether the file will be exactly  512 bytes in size.